# Prove: $A \bigtriangleup C \subseteq A \bigtriangleup B \implies (A \bigtriangleup C) \cap (B \bigtriangleup C) = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

I'm having a bit of hard time to write the proof (FOL), I understand it but can't find a path of statements to prove the objective.

My prove so far(translated):

> Need to prove: A△C ⊆ A△B ⇒ (A△C) ∩ (B△C) = Ø 
> suppose A△C ⊆ A△B, ntp: (A△C) ∩ (B△C) = Ø 
> Simplifying the objective: 
> ¬∃x(x∈(A△C) ∧ x∈(B△C)) 
> ∀ x ¬(x∈(A△C) ∧ x∈(B△C))    (de-morgan identity) 
> ∀ x (x∉(A△C) ∨ x∉(B△C))    (¬→ ≡ ∨)  
> suppose ¬(x∉(A△C)), now need to prove: x∉(B△C) 
> let x ∈ A△C, to prove: x∉(B△C) 
> we can prove instead: x∉((B∪C) \ (B∩C)) 
> in other words: ¬(x∈(B∪C) ∧ x∉(B∩C))    (de-morgan) 
> x∉(B∪C) ∨ x∈(B∩C) %nbsp;%nbsp; (¬→ ≡ ∨) 
> suppose ¬x∉(B∪C), now need to prove: x∈(B∩C)

and here I'm stuck. I've tried to start over several times, I might be wrong in the simplification of the objective. But I just don't know where I am wrong or missing something. I'm still a new student in the Naive-Set-Theory course, and this is part of our first assignment.

Comment: Removed group-theory tag. This is not about groups.

Comment: This doesn't help with constructing your proof, but one could prove the implication by deducing it from the symmetrical result that for all sets $A, B, C,$
$$
(B \bigtriangleup C) \cap (C \bigtriangleup A) \cap
(A \bigtriangleup B) = \emptyset.
$$
I hadn't seen this neat little identity before, but your question suggested it - thanks! (By the way, please use MathJax - see [How to Ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice).)

Comment: As for why the identity holds: for all $x,$ the set $\{\chi_A(x), \chi_B(x), \chi_C(x)\}$ is a subset of $\{0, 1\},$ so it has at most $2$ elements, therefore either $\chi_B(x) = \chi_C(x)$ or $\chi_C(x) = \chi_A(x)$ or $\chi_A(x) = \chi_B(x),$ i.e., either $x \notin B \bigtriangleup C$ or $x \notin C \bigtriangleup A$ or $x \notin A \bigtriangleup B.$ (For the notation $\chi_A,$ see [Indicator function - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley That is a neat identity. Looks like a Jacobi identity.

Answer (score 1):

Take $x\in (A\triangle C) \cap (B\triangle C)$. I.e,
$$ x\in (A\setminus C)\cup (C\setminus A)\quad \mbox{and}\quad x\in (B\setminus C) \cup (C\setminus B). $$
Suppose $x\in A\setminus B$. Then $x\notin B$ implies that $x\in C\setminus B$. So $x\in C$, which implies $x\in C\setminus A$, a contradiction. Similar contradiction emerges if $x\in B\setminus A$. Therefore $A\triangle C \not\subseteq A\triangle B$.

---

Alternatively, as mentioned in the comments, one may note that for all sets $A,B,C$ we have
$$ (A\triangle B) \cap (B\triangle C) \cap (C\triangle A) = \emptyset. $$
Given $A\triangle C \subseteq A\triangle B$, it follows that
$$ (A\triangle B) \cap (B\triangle C) = ((A\triangle B) \cap (A\triangle C)) \cap (B\triangle C) =\emptyset. $$

Comment: Very informative thanks. Still can’t upvote comments.